# Not able to access WSO2 IoTS Device Management Console in wso2-iot-3.0.0

Tags: wso2-iot

I am currently using wso2iot-3.0.0 in my 64-bit ubuntu machine. I have installed all the prerequisites. Now I am in the very first stage of running the product where I am able to access the IOTS management console but not able to access the device management console. I am getting these logs while running the wso2server.sh file in <PRODUCT_HOME>/analytics/bin directory.
Please help me I am very new to this product.

Thanks in advance

```
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,769] [IoT-Broker] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer} -  status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.isAuthorized(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.isAuthorizedForTopic(DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.java:143)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.ProtocolProcessor.processSubscribe(ProtocolProcessor.java:854)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:186)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:47)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,780] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,838] [IoT-Broker]  INFO {org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.ProtocolProcessor} -  cleaning old saved subscriptions for client paho4831733450611910
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,874] [IoT-Broker]  INFO {org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.ProtocolProcessor} -  cleaning old saved subscriptions for client paho4831733668307992
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,889] [IoT-Broker] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer} -  status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.isAuthorized(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.isAuthorizedForTopic(DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.java:143)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.ProtocolProcessor.processSubscribe(ProtocolProcessor.java:854)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:186)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:47)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,892] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,910] [IoT-Broker] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer} -  status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading DeviceAccessAuthorizationAdminService#isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest); content:
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/api/device-mgt/v1.0/admin/authorization) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.isAuthorized(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.extensions.device.mgt.mqtt.authorization.DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.isAuthorizedForTopic(DeviceAccessBasedMQTTAuthorizer.java:143)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.ProtocolProcessor.processSubscribe(ProtocolProcessor.java:854)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:186)
    at org.dna.mqtt.moquette.messaging.spi.impl.SimpleMessaging.onEvent(SimpleMessaging.java:47)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:13,912] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:30,014] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:30,087] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:30,134] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:19:30,993] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers
[2017-02-08 05:19:47,974] [IoT-Core]  INFO - CarbonWebappClassLoader Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappClassLoader.loadClass(CarbonWebappClassLoader.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.keySet(DiskStore.java:521)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:828)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:20:02,320] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:20:02,408] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:20:02,437] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:20:56,065] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappClassLoader} -  Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappClassLoader.loadClass(CarbonWebappClassLoader.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.keySet(DiskStore.java:521)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:828)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:21:06,518] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:21:06,542] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:21:06,576] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:23:14,712] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-02-08 05:23:14,721] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
```

Answer (score 0):

Above error is thrown on analytics, This can happen if you start the analytics before core. Could you verify whether core is up. In addition the above trace doesn't show anything related to devicemgt console.

Comment: Ya i have now followed the sequence of starting the server as : broker, core then analytics. But I am getting the following errors

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the server. The problem seems to be with wso2iot-3.0.0 with posting the SAML login request.

Logging in into the device mgt provides following post page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 not importanr
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>
        You are now being redirected to Identity Server. If the redirection fails, please click on
        the button below.
    </p>

    <form method="post" action="https://%iot.keymanager.host%:%iot.keymanager.https.port%/samlsso">
        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="..." />
        <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="SSOAuthSessionID" value="..." />
        <button type="submit">Redirect manually</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So apparently the template parameters **https://%iot.keymanager.host%:%iot.keymanager.https.port%/samlsso** are not evaluated properly. I will try to check if there's an issue for this or raise one

The exception provided seems to be really about the MQTT client not able to connect to the broker, seems nothing to do with being unable to connect to the device manager

Created ticket: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IOTS-487